# mongoDB PHP aggregate collection by date and sum field per date

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am attempting to output an array of dates grouped by date with a sum of a field called `minutes_numeric`.

My current query is:

```
return $this->db->Work->aggregate(array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lt' => $end)
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'year' => array('$year' => '$date' ),
                    'month' => array('$month' => '$date' ),
                    'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$date'),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
                    'minutes_numeric' => array('$sum' => 1)
                ),
            ),
            array(
                '$sort' => array(
                    '_id' => 1
                ),
            ),
            array(
                '$limit' => 30
            )
        ));
```

Which outputs:

```
{
result: [
{
_id: {
year: 2013,
month: 12,
day: 4
},
minutes_numeric: 40
},
{
_id: {
year: 2013,
month: 12,
day: 11
},
minutes_numeric: 127
},
{
_id: {
year: 2013,
month: 12,
day: 12
},
minutes_numeric: 108
}
],
ok: 1
}
```

Which is great, however the `minutes_numeric` represents the number of rows for that day, so I changed the `$group` clause:

```
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
            'minutes_numeric' => array('$sum' => '$minutes_numeric')
        ),
    ),
```

Which then changes the sum (minutes_numeric) to 0 and not an actual sum.

I'm unsure why my sum is going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated

---

Edit,

If I update the $project to include minutes_numeric then the sum seems to exclude the $match parameters

```
 array(
            '$project' => array(
                'year' => array('$year' => '$date' ),
                'month' => array('$month' => '$date' ),
                'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$date'),
                'minutes_numeric' => 1
            ),
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
                'minutes_numeric' => array('$sum' => '$minutes_numeric')
            ),
        )
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand "the sum seems to exclude the $match parameters", what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you share with us the results after the edit you made?

Comment: please provide an actual document in your collection.  I suspect "minutes_numeric" is not a simple top level field.

Answer (score 0):

If this is you current query

```
return $this->db->Work->aggregate(array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lt' => $end)
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'year' => array('$year' => '$date' ),
                    'month' => array('$month' => '$date' ),
                    'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$date'),
                    'minutes_numeric' => 1
                ),
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
                    'minutes_numeric' => array('$sum' => '$minutes_numeric')
                ),
            ),
            array(
                '$sort' => array(
                    '_id' => 1
                ),
            ),
            array(
                '$limit' => 30
            )
        ));
```

then the only way your $match parameters are "ignored" and the results are not as you expect is probably because they are wrong. Try checking the values of $start and $end, because the query you are using seems correct.

In case that is not the problem please update your question with the results of your current query. (Also update your query if it is different than the one in my answer)

Comment: actually, date range should probably be $gte and not $gt.  but I suspect the real issue is that minutes_numeric is not a top level field.

Comment: you mean you're attempting to compute minutes_numeric on the fly in the query, and it does not actually exist in the fields of the collection, right ? If so, please explain how you intend to compute it.

Comment: Inside the $group object of an aggregation pipeline you can compute/create a new field on the fly so i don't think there is a problem weather that field exists in the documents of the collection or not. Also the $gt vs $gte is not probably a reason that the $match parameter is getting "excluded" (whatever that may mean).